# How to serve CherryPy application in mulitple ports independently?

Tags: python, multithreading, wsgi, cherrypy, cherrypywsgiserver

I am using CherryPy to serve my application in multiple ports say 8080 and 8081

```
cherrypy.server.unsubscribe()

for port in [8080, 8081]:
    server = Server()
    server.socket_port = port
    server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
    server.thread_pool = 100
    server.subscribe()
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

With this the application is being served as expected on both the ports. Now due to some reason I want to stop the server of a specific port and other being served normally. When I stop the process on a particular port with the following command,

```
fuser -k "$port"/tcp
```

All the process on the ports in which the application was started (8080, 8081) are also being killed. Is this an expected behaviour ?

If yes, is there anyway I can achieve serving the application independently without affecting the other ports on which it is running ? (Other than like I should change the port in the source code and run it again manually)

If no, what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `fuser -k` kills processes, what did you expect when you bind to two ports within the same process?

Comment: @webKnjaZ you are correct, As I already asked in the question,is there anyway I can achieve serving the application independently ?

Comment: It depends on your definition of independence. You could run separate processes, for example. Or you could implement some mechanism that would be triggering `server.stop()` call. But a better question would be is this really what you want? You didn't state the problem you're trying to solve, only the desired solution.

Comment: you could also just block the network traffic on the iptables level, but again you need to understand what fits your needs.

Comment: My problem is, first I ran the application in a single port with 100 threads, and now I have to scale up to serve more concurrent requests, So I thought of increasing the server instance by running it on multiple ports, with each having allocated 200 threads and with a load balancer. It works good, sometimes due to RAM overload issues, the whole application goes down. If it is independent, then a specific process would go down and the others would continue to serve. So I just want to know if running separate processes by starting the servers one by one is the only solution or anything else ?